# Log In With Paypal Unauthorized 'error:access_denied'

Tags: c#, paypal, webclient

I am attempting to set up [Log In With Paypal](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/log-in-with-paypal/), but I am receiving a Unauthorized Message ("{\"error_description\":\"Unable to generate token\",\"error\":\"access_denied\"}") while obtaining the access token ( I received the authorization code without a hiccup). The only thing I think I might have wrong is the availability of this service to non US residents. It says that REST APIs is not available to non US residents, but I noticed that its segregated from the 'Log In With Paypal'. Does anyone know?

Here is the code I am using too retrieve the access token in case anyone can notice an error:

```
        string TokenEndpoint = "https://api.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/tokenservice"; 
        System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection reqparm = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();

        reqparm.Add("client_id", this._clientId);
        reqparm.Add("client_secret", this._clientSecret);
        reqparm.Add("grant_type", "authorization_code");
        reqparm.Add("code", authorizationCode);
        reqparm.Add("redirect_uri", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl.AbsoluteUri));

        try
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                var data = client.UploadValues(TokenEndpoint, "POST", reqparm); // Access Denied exception occurs here.
                ...
```

Here is the response I receive:

```
HEADER
{
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: close
Content-Length: 72
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Type: application/json
    Date: Mon, 10 Jun 2013 23:35:02 GMT
    Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
}
Content
text    
{   
    \"error_description\":\"Unable to generate token\",
    \"error\":\"access_denied\"
}"
```

Comment: Login with PayPal is certainly available outside the US, so that shouldn't be your problem. Can you please include the full response in your post, including the HTTP response headers?

Comment: I've added the HTTP response Header and Content. Let me know If I can provide anything else that may be advantageous.

Comment: We've looked at it and can't spot any obvious errors - can you file a ticket with us at https://www.paypal.com/mts and include your client_id (not secret) and application name? If you share the ticket# I'll get it prioritized.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will open a ticket immediately as I am still struggling with this issue.

Comment: Here is the tickets Reference #: 130611-000217. Let me know If I can provide anything else that may be advantageous.